# подключение к базе данных на WSL2 через Goland

Tags: база-данных, jetbrains, wsl2, goland

Через Goland (как и другие IDEA JetBrains) можно подключиться к базам данных через GUI и при подключении к базам данных, которые стоят на Винде, проблем не возникает, но вот подключиться к БД, которая стоит на WSL2, не получается. Пробовал разные способы: создавал разных юзеров и там, и там, указывал разный хост, пробовал через сокет - ничего не вышло. Может кто-то сталкивался с таким и мог бы помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377052/how-to-connect-to-wsl-mysql-from-host-windows) и оттуда мне помогло смена порта у MySQL сервера на WSL. Скорее всего можно так же поменять и порт сервера на винде.